# golang - modulus using math big package

Tags: go

Reading up the documentation - http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/

*Mod sets z to the modulus x%y for y != 0 and returns z. If y == 0, a division-by-zero run-time panic occurs. Mod implements Euclidean modulus (unlike Go); see DivMod for more details.*

10%4 = 2 but I get 8 with this (using the math/big package to do the same thing) - http://play.golang.org/p/_86etDvLYq

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "math/big"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    ten := new(big.Int)
    ten.SetBytes([]byte(strconv.Itoa(10)))

    four := new(big.Int)
    four.SetBytes([]byte(strconv.Itoa(4)))

    tenmodfour := new(big.Int)
    tenmodfour = tenmodfour.Mod(ten, four)

    fmt.Println("mod", tenmodfour)

}
```

I most likely got something wrong. Where's the mistake?

Comment: Try printing out "ten" and "four".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `SetBytes` is not doing what you think! Use `SetInt64` instead.

```
ten := new(big.Int)
ten.SetBytes([]byte(strconv.Itoa(10)))

four := new(big.Int)
four.SetBytes([]byte(strconv.Itoa(4)))

fmt.Println(ten, four)
```

Result:

```
12592 52
```

And indeed, `12592%52 == 8`

If you want to use numbers bigger than what `int64` lets you manipulate, you can also use the `SetString` function:

```
n := new(big.Int)
n.SetString("456135478645413786350", 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just an addition to [julienc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24099074/145587)'s answer, if you were to use `SetBytes`, you have to convert the number to bytes like [`this`](http://play.golang.org/p/TOpvuLZFoj) :

```
func int2bytes(num int) (b []byte) {
    b = make([]byte, 4)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(b, uint32(num))
    return
}
func main() {
    ten := new(big.Int)
    ten.SetBytes(int2bytes(10))

    four := new(big.Int)
    four.SetBytes(int2bytes(4))

    fmt.Println(ten, four)

    tenmodfour := new(big.Int)
    tenmodfour = tenmodfour.Mod(ten, four)

    fmt.Println("mod", tenmodfour)
}
```